# Do we have any diamonds left?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Cyn is taking a leave of absence, Monica was removed, the others have stepped down...

So now what?

Comment: I honestly am bewildered and disappointed.  I'm thinking about stepping away from the site, too, although I am but a simple user.  Cyn and Monica were two mods and people who made me very proud to be a part of this community, and seeing what's happening--it's like a fireball.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate in a way: [No more active ♦ moderators. How should we keep the site in order?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6333/63243) Go on and wait for the staff to do something or step away, too. I know which of those I will do after... [this...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/352819)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**The simple answer is just no.**

At present, after [Monica was removed](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2228/2533) ([also](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193/8987)), [I stepped down](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2229/2533), [Neil resigned](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2230/2533), and [Cyn is taking a leave of absence](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2243/2533), **there are no active community moderators left on Writing SE.**

<strike>While at least I still technically have a diamond, I for one am merely waiting for a Stack Exchange employee to remove it, and I have not performed any moderation activities on either site where I've had a diamond, since I posted about my stepping down about 46 hours ago.</strike> Both my own and Neil's diamond moderator access has now been revoked.

**What happens next is up to Stack Exchange Inc.** There has been much speculation in different places, but as far as I can tell, [the official update posted a few hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/157730) does not address that issue at all. (A [second apology and update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/157730) was posted later, but also does not appear to address this.)

Comment: The official update is one of the poorest attempts at an apology I have ever seen...it neither was helpful to the situation nor an acknowledgement of fault/error. I expected more from them.

Comment: @JCrosby - I don't. It's a pretty standard corporate response.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone *will* come and remove your diamond. Having no visible moderation left on their sites? That'd be like admitting they messed up, or something.

Comment: @WeckarE On the other hand: (1) the explicitly stated policy is that moderators can step down at any time, if they want to; if SE does not accept a resignation request from a moderator in good standing, that would be a *huge* issue *all on its own*. (2) Having an actively high-privilege account even with, let alone against, the wishes of the account holder is a potential liability. I won't deliberately damage the site, and feel rather confident in my ability to secure my account, but should a diamond-moderator account be compromised somehow, the attacker can do a huge amount of damage quickly.